How to apply a .css style to a div tag with air flight board effect
I have the following "div" in HTML,
<div id="random_decimal" class="departure-board">
    {{ x }}
</div>

Even though the departure-board class is applied to the div tag, I get as a result,

The variable x, which is enclosed in braces, is displayed using jinja2. I want the content of x to be displayed using the style departure-board.css,
the departure-board.css file was taken from the link,
https://github.com/paulcuth/departure-board/tree/master

I only want to apply the style departure-board.css to the variable x, I have tried to use the departure-board.css file but I do not have the effect I am looking for, any guide would be appreciated,
/*
    Based upon Jakub Hampl's "Designing a departures board with CSS3".
    http://gampleman.eu/post/1488470623/designing-a-departures-board-with-css3
*/




.departure-board {
    padding:  0.36em;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.21em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.21em;
    border-radius: 0.21em;
    color: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}


.departure-board span.letter {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    margin: 0 .1em;
    height: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}


.departure-board span.letter {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        inset 0 -.07em 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, .7), 
        inset 0 -.14em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), 
        inset .14em 0 .28em rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), 
        inset -.14em 0 .28em rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), 
        0 .07em 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2); 

    -moz-box-shadow: 
        inset 0 -.07em 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, .7), 
        inset 0 -.14em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), 
        inset .14em 0 .28em rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), 
        inset -.14em 0 .28em rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), 
        0 .07em 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2); 

    -o-box-shadow: 
        inset 0 -.07em 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, .7), 
        inset 0 -.14em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), 
        inset .14em 0 .28em rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), 
        inset -.14em 0 .28em rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), 
        0 .07em 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2); 

    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 -.07em 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, .7), 
        inset 0 -.14em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), 
        inset .14em 0 .28em rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), 
        inset -.14em 0 .28em rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), 
        0 .07em 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);  
}


.departure-board span.letter:before {
    border-top: .07em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    border-bottom: .07em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .08);
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: .62em;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
   -moz-transform: translate(0, -.05em);
   -o-transform: translate(0, -.1em);
}


.departure-board span.fold {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    top: .65em;
}


.departure-board span.flap {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0em;   
    width: 1em;
    height: .65em;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.departure-board span.text {
    width: 100%;
}


.departure-board span.bottom {
    top: .65em;
}


.departure-board span.bottom span.text {
    position: relative;
    top: -.65em;
}



.departure-board span.flap.falling {
    display: none;
    bottom: 0;  
    top: auto;
}


.departure-board span.flap.falling span.text {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-top: .03em solid #444;
    border-bottom: .03em solid #444;    
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1); 
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1); 
    -o-transform: scaleY(1); 
    transform: scaleY(1); 

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform linear;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform linear;
    -o-transition: -o-transform linear;
    transition: transform linear;
 }

thanks

Note that no browser has needed those vendor prefixes in maybe 10 years or more.
